Where should I begin to understand $\mathcal I_{\Gamma}$ in complex space?
Motivation: What is the largest surface of revolution with constant positive Gaussian curvature that can be embedded in $X^3=[0,1]^3$ with a pair of antipodal corners as cone points? It can be shown that there is a unique surface solution to this question. Therefore, replicating this surface three more times within $X^3$ where each copy is paired with distinct antipodal cone points, we get the Interface construction, which is the union of these four surfaces, or leaves.
Let the Interface Construction be denoted by $ \mathcal{I} $. Given the symmetry and unique structural constraints of $ \mathcal{I} $, we expect its associated $\Gamma$-set—denoted $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} $—to be unique and particularly rigid among all possible $\Gamma$-sets within this construction framework. This uniqueness and rigidity arise from the geometrically constrained configuration of $ \mathcal{I} $, which imposes minimization of variation in the structure.

To rigorously characterize $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} $, we define it as follows:
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} := \bigcup_{j=1}^3 \left( \mathcal{I} \cap \{x_j = 1/2\} \right),
$$
where $ \{x_1, x_2, x_3\} $ are the standard coordinates on $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ and the planes $ \{x_j = 1/2\}$ represent the intersections of $ \mathcal{I} $ with the coordinate planes $ x = \frac{1}{2}, y = \frac{1}{2}, $ and $ z = \frac{1}{2} $. This construction partitions $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} $ into three distinct components:
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} = \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,1} \cup \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,2} \cup \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,3},
$$
where $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,j} := \mathcal{I} \cap \{x_j = 1/2\} $ are pairs of intersecting quartic varieties. For example re-scaling the cube to $[-1,1]^3$ we get the variety:
$$x^4+2 x^2 y^2+y^4-14 x^2+8 x y-14 y^2+9=0$$
where by reflections we can obtain the rest of the quartics on the other planar cross sections.
We also consider normal bundles defined on each of the four leaves comprising $ \mathcal{I} $, denoted by $ L_i $ for $ i = 1, \ldots, 4 $, which are restricted to $\mathcal I_{\Gamma}$ forming an interesting structure:


I would like to embed $\mathcal I_{\Gamma}$ in $\Bbb C^2$ to analyze it in a larger space along with their bundles inherited from the $L_i$.

Where should I begin to understand $\mathcal I_{\Gamma}$ in complex space? How does the bundle on $\mathcal I_{\Gamma}$ change from the $\Bbb R^3$ to complex space?

I would like to understand the holonomy of the bundle in question, which is why I ask about looking at it in a larger space.

This is much more of a complex or differential geometry question than an algebraic geometry question. Please consider more appropriately tagging it by removing the algebraic-geometry tag.
